# How to implement so that when you click on an empty space, close the block

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2

I have a regular block I want to do so that when you click on an empty space, this block closes here is a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hopper-fczsi)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, Did you mean that the box should disappear when you click on empty space?

Comment: Hi, yes, you understood correctly, of course, except for this block :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an event bus to communicate between window click event listener and the component should be one way to go.

You can work on top of this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-ganguly-e8b4b?file=/src/App.vue:304-334)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Using a backdrop and detects when it got clicked. Is this what you want?

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="backdrop" @click.self="showBox = !showBox">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="25%" />
    <HelloWorld :showBox="showBox" msg="Hello Vue in CodeSandbox!" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      showBox: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.backdrop {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="showBox" class="wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
    showBox: Boolean,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```